# reading json in javascript which is encoded by php

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have json encoded array in php and it looks something like below

```
["Assam","Chennai","Delhi+%26+NCR","Himachal+Pradesh","Karnataka","Kolkata"];
```

i wanted to read all the above value in javascript.But i dont get it working.I have read lots of related questions which provide solutions like eval..But i get undefined error.

```
eval('var result = ' +response);
alert(result.data);
```

note : var **response** is returning  `["Assam","Chennai","Delhi+%26+NCR","Himachal+Pradesh","Karnataka","Kolkata"];` but result.data is undefined.some one please guide me.

Comment: That is an array not an object.  There is no `.data` property.  Try `alert(result[0])`.  Also, *please* use `JSON.parse()` instead of `eval()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have there is an array, not an object.  There is no `.data` property.  Try to access it as an array: `alert(result[0]);`.

Also, *please* do not use `eval()` for this purpose.  Use `JSON.parse()`.

```
var result = JSON.parse(response);
alert(response[0]);  // Assam
```